# Inset 3 headers for REST API tokens

Tags: excel, rest, api, vba

I'm trying to follow a guide, to connect Excel with a website using REST API, but I'm already stuck. I of course got the Tokens it's mentioning.

The guide writes; 
"Add these three headers to your first request:

X-AppSecretToken: TheAppSecretToken

X-AgreementGrantToken: TheAgreementGrantToken

Content-Type: application/json"

But I don't know how to do that in Excel. Does it want me to use Json?

I hope someone is willing and capable to help me with this, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I get you correct you need to set the headers of you Request with

```
SetRequestHeader
```

(Documentation here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/aa384060(v=vs.85).aspx)

And here an example for a GET Request:

```
Dim result As String
Dim URL As String
Dim winHttpReq As Object
Set winHttpReq = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")

URL = "YOURURL"

winHttpReq.Open "GET", URL, False
winHttpReq.SetRequestHeader "X-AppSecretToken", "YOURTOKEN"
winHttpReq.SetRequestHeader "X-AgreementGrantToken", "YOURTOKEN" 
winHttpReq.Send

result = winHttpReq.responseText
```

Hope this helps